# calculate the percentage with sql and DOMO

Tags: sql, domo

I have a table where I want to calculate the percentage of revenue using the following formula: (Advertiser Revenue / Total Revenue) * 100. 
Data =>

```
Partner    Date           Ad Unit   Revenue   Total Revenue
App        1/1/2020       x         10        13
App        1/1/202        y         3         13
```

Here is my code and what I have tried:

```
SELECT ad.`Partner`,
       ad.`Date`,
       ad.`Ad Unit`,
       ad.`Revenue`,
       ad.`Total Revenue`
      (ad.`Revenue` / ad.`Total Revenue`) * 100 as `Percentage`
FROM `ad_unit_totals` as ad
```

Error: syntax error: execute command denied to user

Comment: Hi there, is this MySQL database? If so, this error means that the user you use to connect to your database does not have select grant to at least that table.

Comment: It is in DOMO and I have created the table myself, so definitely should have an access.

Comment: Well, in any other database you can have create grants to create tables and not select grant, the error would be the same. May worth taking a look on how your permissions are

Comment: I have admin rights, but I'll look into it. I'll try anything at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Domo, this calculation would best be done at the visualization layer using Beast Mode. Just create your beast mode that is `Revenue` / `Total Revenue`.